# Can not do pagination using mvc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

giving error - (extension) IPageList IQueryable, ToPagedList(int pageNumber, int pageSize) (+2 overload(s))

Create a subset of this collection of objects than can individually accessed by index and containing metadata about the collection of objects the subset was created from.

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList(System.Linq.IQueryable, int, int)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Pagination.ToPagedList(System.Linq.IQueryable, int, int)'

Pls. send me a answer with sample example so that I can understand my error. I am new in MVC.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: This isn't really an MVC issue at all - you've got two methods with the same signature, and the .NET framework doesn't know which one to use.  Just remove or alias one of them.